# Showing the user who last commented a post (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Post* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

a *User* model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :avatar, :subscribed_tag_names

  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and a *Comment* model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is how I show the user who created the post in the **index.html.erb** view:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div id="post-<%= post.id %>" class="post">
      <h3 class="post-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
      <div class="post-author">
        <span class="profile-picture">
          <%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
        </span>
        <span class="post-author-name">
          <strong><%= link_to post.user.username, post.user %></strong>
        </span>
      </div>
```

(etc...)

How to display the user who last commented the post (as you can see in StackOverflow and various forums)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer only works when your post has some comments. When there are no comments then you will receive an error, as you have noted.

You could solve this by simply testing that comments exist before trying to output it:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ...

  <% if post.comments.empty? %>
    Nobody has commented yet
  <% else %>
    <%= post.comments.last.user.email %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% comment = post.comments.order(:created_at).reverse_order.first %>
<%= comment.user.email if comment %>
```

This does the following:

it get all comments of the post, ordered by the `created_at` field in reverse order (i.e. the largest value on top). From that, it selects the first value, i.e. the newest comment. From that comment, you then get the `user`.

Setting the order is non-optional as databases are free to return elements in an arbitrary order if it is not specified explicitly. You will observe the random order more often on Postgres or Oracle than on MySQL or SQLite because of the way they store records. However, all of them will return random element orders at least occasionally if the order is not specified.

Comment: post.comments.last will order them by creation date by default and return the last value.

Comment: @Jon: Only if you define your relation as `has_many :comments, :order_by => :created_at` or by defining a `default_scope`on the Comment model. Rails will generally not apply ordering unless told so.

Comment: Ah, just looked up the rails source and it orders by primary_key DESC by default. I suppose reversing the order and selecting the first might be a little quicker on a large dataset too. I guess that depends on the backend database being used.

Comment: According to [the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reverse_order) only reverse_order introduces the order by primary key (if no order was specified). But there is still no implicit default order on associations unless you have set it somewhere. The generated SQL just doesn't include any notion of order by default.

Comment: Are you sure? What about the reverse primary key order used here? - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83e42d52e37a33682fcac856330fd5d06e5a529c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L134

Comment: Okay, you got me there. But still, this is not something I would rely on (as it's an exception from the rule) and it doesn't solve the OP's issue. It will probably work most of the time there, but only by accident.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ...

  <%= post.comments.last.user.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: for some reason I'm getting `undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass`. Maybe because some posts don't have comments. How can I solve that?