# Active record. Model.Find.last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord relationship between `Trade` and `Execution`. I can get

```
Trade.executions  #returns all exeuctions realated to the Trade
```

If I do

```
Trade.executions.last
```

It seems seems to return the last execution record based on ID.

Is this the correct way to retrieve the last execution record related to Trade based on ID?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, that's not guaranteed to give you the Execution with the highest `id`. If you don't specify an explicit ordering then the records can come out of the database in any order. The fact that they look like they're sorted by `id` is just a convenient accident.

You should do one of these:

```
highest_id_execution = trade.executions.order(:id).last
highest_id_execution = trade.executions.order('id desc').first
```

That will give you the execution for `trade` that has the highest `id`. If you really want the most recently created one then you should `order(:created_at)` instead:

```
most_recent_execution = trade.executions.order(:created_at).last
most_recent_execution = trade.executions.order('created_at desc').first
```

The `id` and `created_at` columns will almost always come in the same order but you should say what you mean to make things clearer to the people that maintain your code.

In both cases, the `order(:x).last` and `order('x desc').first` are exactly the same and even resolve to exactly the same SQL so use whichever one makes the most sense to you.

Comment: +1, You can add an `:order` option to the `executions ` association, i.e. `has_many :executions, :order => "executions.created_at"`, this way  `trade.executions.last` returns the last execution based on `timestamp` rather than `id`.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: True enough but I prefer minimal associations to avoid unnecessary ORDER BYs and `reorder`s.

Comment: I understand, I use this approach in very rare cases where over-riding the default sort order makes the association intuitive.

Comment: In fact `Trade.executions.last` does force to order by primary key of executions unless you specified something other. So `trade.executions.order(:id).last` is 100% equivalent to `trade.executions.last` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9654437/421705 for a discussion. However I fully support your remarks about ordering by `created_at`.

Comment: @HolgerJust: No it doesn't, look at the generated SQL: no ORDER BY clause means no reliable order. Usually the rows will come out in PK order but there is no guarantee of that: a table has no natural order. ActiveRecord may have included a default ORDER BY clause at some time in the past but it certainly doesn't do it now.

Comment: @muistooshort: That's what I thought too (look at the linked discussion). However looking at the source ([here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83e42d52e37a33682fcac856330fd5d06e5a529c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L134) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83e42d52e37a33682fcac856330fd5d06e5a529c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L381) convinced me otherwise. In fact there are a couple of places where Rails applies some default ordering.

Comment: @HolgerJust: but I don't see it in the SQL and given my experience with Rails, it is best to be explicit. OTOH, I am a professional heretic. Is the ordering behavior documented and guaranteed or does it just happen in a few places in the source code?

Comment: I see it in the SQL (at least in my 2.3.14 app). And it's documented [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reverse_order) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#last). But you are right, being explicit (at least sometimes) beats being implicit. The order being one of those places.

Comment: @HolgerJust: Looks it is doing an ORDER BY behind your back with `last`. Maybe I've been using too many ORMs (and hating them all for one thing or another :) at the same time lately.

Answer (score 1):

`#last` will return the last record based on primary key. If your primary key is not `id`, then you will need to be more explicit.

This is both in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#last) and the [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83e42d52e37a33682fcac856330fd5d06e5a529c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L134)

As @muistooshort mentioned, it doesn't hurt to be explicit :)